# Transferring the package... > Fail Error occurred at the below step. `Transferring the package...` (Return Code:2)unknown error

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

When i deploy my Tizen project on emulator then it's giving a error **"Transferring the package... > Fail Error occurred at the below step.  `Transferring the package...`  (Return Code:2)unknown error"** .
How can i fix it, and also on developer mode in my emulator.

Comment: Is this for the TV or wearable?  Version of the IDE/emulator?  Any additional details would be helpful.

Comment: This is for TV and Tizen IDE Version : 2.4.0_Rev6.

Comment: Did you setup your author & device certificates?  If so, did you do "Permit to install applications" on the emulator?  Sorry for so many questions, but you'll learn this IDE can be very fickle if every step isn't followed exactly as expected.  And, as you've seen, the returned error messages are usually less than helpful.

Comment: I did "Permit to install applications" on the emulator and now all is working..    Thanks.davesaus

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this issue was:

- Make sure both author and device certificates were setup properly.
- From the 'Connection Explorer' in the Tizen IDE, right-click on the
  device, then select 'Permit to install applications'.

Comment: I have TizenStudio 1.1.0 and don't have the 'Permit to install applications' in the right-click menu. I'm getting this error, and I think that the problem is that I'm missing this permission.

Comment: To make the "Permit to install applications" action available, install "Samsung Certificate Extension" (you find it in the "Extension SDK"-tab in the Package Manager). ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994548/tizen-app-not-installing-on-device/41003293#41003293))