# Tizen app not installing on device

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio, tizen-certificate

I'm trying to install a simple app (built from samples) on Samsung Tizen Z2 device using Tizen Studio 1.0.1 on both MacOS,Win7 and getting error 23: Signature verification failed.

My device shows properly in Connection Explorer. Also generated the certificate using Certificate Manager. Please help.

Comment: Check privileges  ...is there any unnecessary privileges  or you missed any privileges which is needed for your app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check privileges. Is there any unnecessary privileges or you missed any privileges which is needed for your app.

If you think you have generated the certificate appropriately, the right click on the device id from connection explorer and click "**permit to install**".

If you still face the problem, remove all the certificates you have created. You may follow [this](http://developer.samsung.com/z/develop/getting-certificates/create) guide carefully. I think, the problem is with certificate type.

Please make sure you have installed **Samsung certificate extention** from **Package Manager**.

[image]

And you have created **Samsung certificate** not the **Tizen certificate**.

---

Addendum:

If the **Samsung Certificate Extension** is not showing up in the **Extension SDK**-Tab it must first be enabled in the **Package Manager** - **Configuration**, accesible via the tools-icon.
[image: Package Manager - Config Extension SDK]

Comment: When I click on + in Certificate Manager, I don't see the option to choose between Tizen or Samsung type! Also "Permit to Install" option is not present. The app is a simple one and doesn't need any privileges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to install Samsung certificate extension from Extension SDK. That solved the issue.

Comment: I get "The current device does not need permit to install step". What should i do? I have 2 different watches and the app works there.

Comment: Right Click on device from Connection Explorer and click "Permit to install"