# Cannot transfer Tizen App to Smartwatch

Tags: tizen, samsung-gear, tizen-studio

Using Tizen Studio on a Debian PC, I cannot launch the Hello World App on the Smartwatch.
When I launch the app, the following error arises:

```
'Launching Basic' has encountered a problem.
Installing the package... > Fail
 Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
 `Installing the package...`
Please try again later.
```

I use the Samsung Gear S, connected via USB.

Related:
[Transferring the package... > Fail Error occurred at the below step. `Transferring the package...` (Return Code:2)unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384932/transferring-the-package-fail-error-occurred-at-the-below-step-transferri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to

## Create a Samsung Author and Distribution Certificate

This is also handled in other answers, however I had a hard time following them since they were not complete. Hence once again:

1. Install the Samsung Certificate Extension. In TizenStudio, go to "Tools" -> "Package Manager". Navigate to the "Extension SDK"-Tab. If you have troubles, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994548/tizen-app-not-installing-on-device/41003293#41003293).
2. Go to "Tools" -> "Certificate Manager". It will now look different than before installing the Extension SDK. Click on "SAMSUNG", then select Mobile/Wearable, then follow the instructions (choose arbitrary name, author, password, ...).
3. You will be asked for a Samsung account. If you don't have one, create it, it is rather painless.
4. Create a Backup or not, then create a new Distributor Certificate

   1. You need to add an individual DUID (the one of your device), if your device is connected at this time, it will probably be filled in for you.
   2. If you need advanced privileges (e.g. you access the heart rate within your app), you need to change the *Privilege* field from *Public* to *Partner*.
   3. Default values worked for me in the other fields.
5. It will prompt that the Certificate was created successfully. Check if the newly created profile is selected (indicated by the tick) Close the Certificate Manager.
6. Open the Connection Manager (for me it was already open at the right side of TizenStudio). Right-click on your device and click on the last action "Permit to install applications".

## Selecting the correct Version

If I launched the app now, the very same error occurs again.

7. In the Project Explorer, open config.xml, then go to the "Tizen"-Tab and change the "Required Version" to 1.0 (2.0 worked for me too).

Finally, I was able to launch the app on the watch.

Comment: Re step 7, for a native app, in `tizen-manifest.xml`, I needed to set `api-version="3.0"` (Tizen OS version from the device).